# In Unity, using UnityWebRequest, I cant print the body of the object I want

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, http-post

I used to do a post request using native C#'s library

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(djangoApi + user);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"wallet_id\":\""+wallet+"\"," +
                          "\"token\":\"foo\"}";
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

but that doesn't work on mobile. So, I need to use UnityWebRequest

Following the example, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html, my functions look almost identical. Here is the coroutine function

```
IEnumerator SendPostCoroutine()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("user_id", "0x241477cE189fa014292d99e0807cB449b878");
        form.AddField("token", "foo");

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(djangoApi + user, form))
        {
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("POST successful!");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> dict in www.GetResponseHeaders())
                {
                    sb.Append(dict.Key).Append(": \t[").Append(dict.Value).Append("]\n");
                }

                // Print Headers
                Debug.Log(sb.ToString());

                string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(www.downloadHandler.data);
                Debug.Log(response);
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

            }
        }

    }
```

When I do

```
string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(www.downloadHandler.data);
Debug.Log(response);
Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
```

neither prints out the body of the object I want. Instead, all I get is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

What can I do to get the values within the json?

Comment: First make sure that server actually returns a JSON .. it doesn't seem so ... What do you see if you click on the log entry in the console? Usually the logs are trimmed to 2 lines but if you click on it you see the full message ... I suspect an error html page returned instead of the JSON. Btw you should use `Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);` and the first ocurrence of it is useless since it happens before the download finished

Comment: @derHugo Yes, I'm expected to get a JSON. I've edited the way I do it previously, and its a JSON object that I receive. I am wondering if `WWWForm` sends the paramaters as a json object as I think that's what the server needs to receive.

Comment: no it isn't it is sent as a Form with fields and values not as a JSON

Answer (score 0):

I just used

```
IEnumerator Post(string url, string bodyJsonString)
{
    var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
    byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyJsonString);
    request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    yield return request.Send();

    Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.responseCode);
}
```

taken from https://forum.unity.com/threads/posting-json-through-unitywebrequest.476254/. That way, I can post my raw json